# AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET'

Tags: python, sockets

the code was working fine, now it shows the error

AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET'

The code as below: Module name is not socket.py

```
import socket
client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host='192.168.xx.x'
port=4196
client.connect((host, port))
print("connected to IP", host,"and port", port)
```

Error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\New\soc.py", line 1, in <module>
   import socket
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

`

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment. Could you add more information about file/directory status?

Comment: module is named TCP.py it is the only module inside the folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the stack trace it is now clear that you have overwritten the `socket.py` in the standard library with your own code, since the error occurs in the library path `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py` and the code causing the error is clearly yours.

You should re-install Python at this point. Or if you are confident that this is the only file that is corrupted, you can try replacing `socket.py` with the one in the source control [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socket.py).

Comment: This answer looks correct, but you should not be creating a new answer.

Comment: Yes, the file is corrupted. the one you shared is not working. Better I will re-install. thanks for your help

Comment: I replaced with the one in my server,  it worked finally

Comment: I just had the same issue reinstalltion was not needed 
I simply removed the socket.pyc file that you will find in 
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\

after that relaunched the shell all everything working ok again

Answer (score 5):

You're likely to have a module named `socket.py` in your project directory, in which case it will take precedence over the standard module when you do `import socket`. Rename the `socket.py` in your project directory to something else and your code would work.

Comment: No, I don't  have module names sockets.py

Comment: Can you do `print(socket.__file__)` after you `import socket` and tell me what it outputs?

Comment: It prints nothing, just the same error is displayed

Comment: When you say the same error is displayed do you mean the same `AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET'` error? If so, are you sure you're doing `print(socket.__file__)` immediately after `import socket`?

Comment: yes, import socket
print(socket.__file__)
client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: Can you do a `print(type(socket))` instead then? Does it output `<class 'module'>`?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you tell me what output of `print(type(socket))` is?

Comment: it doesn't print anything, it just shows the error message evertime

Comment: Can you comment out everything else and only do `import socket` and `print(type(socket))` (and `print(socket.__file__)`)? I'm suspecting the traceback messages from the `socket.AF_INET` error are overwriting the output from the prints above.

Comment: I still see the same error for "import socket
print(type(socket))"

Comment: That would be impossible if you comment out the rest of the code... You did make the rest of the code comments right? (You can simply put the rest of the code in triple quotes.)

Comment: yes, I did. I am confused why the same error still exist

Comment: Can you update your question with the entire stack trace then?

Comment: the code works completely fine in my server. not sure what is happening local

Comment: Updated with stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

do

```
client= socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: Your code is working fine on my system. You said it was working fine before. Could you tell me what were the changes that you made after which this error started?

Comment: I didn't do much, I am writing in eclipse. I used eclipse to practice some other code

Comment: In that case, could you open your python prompt and see if the code works there?

Comment: >>> import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET'
>>>